# SWIFT access to JSON ARRAY

Tags: arrays, json, swift, weather-api, openweathermap

I have this data from JSON from OpenWeatherMap API

```
"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],
```

I have not idea how to access property "description"...
I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

I have no problem get value from

```
"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0237,"country":"GB","sunrise":1436673470,"sunset":1436732035}
```

using this piece of code:

```
var weatherJson = JSON(json!)
var temperature = weatherJson["main", "temp"].double
.
.
.
func setLabels() {

    if let temp = self.weather?.temp{
     //code
    }
}
```

but that don't work with extra brackets `[]`...

EDIT: SOLUTION ->

```
func getWeatherData(urlString: String) {
var weatherJson = JSON(json!)
var description = weatherJson["weather"][0]["description"].stringValue
}


func setLabels() {
  if let description = self.weather?.desc{
     self.descriptionLabel.text = description
  }
}
```

- "class weather" for stored values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following.

```
var descriptionString = jsonObj["weather"]![0]["description"]
```